# Question on formatting a Tabular Column

Tags: tables

I had a few questions.

1. When I was making a document containing a table containing 10 columns, I was not able to bring all the columns 
   in the page.I tried to fit it by making the margin width 1cm by using the package `geomtery`.
   I also tried to make it tiny.

   ```
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   Modes & LED Status
   & $V_{CE}(P)$(T1)& $V_{CE}(P)$ (T2) &  $V_{CE}(Th.)$(T1) & $V_{CE (Th.)$(T2)
   & $V_{BE}(P)$(T1)&
   $V_{BE}(P)$(T2)
   &$V_{R}$&
   $V_{LED}$\\
   \end{tabular}
   ```
2. I also wanted to center the table in the page. I tried using the code `\centering` and `\begin{center}` and 
   `\end{center}` but was not able to do it.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sideways` environment`and reduce the fontsize  for this table, or reduce the value of`arraycolsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating, array} \usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
  \centering
\caption{A table with many columns}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{10}{c|}}
    \hline
    Modes & LED Status
      & $V_\mathrm{CE}(P)$(T1) & $V_\mathrm{CE}(P)$ (T2) & $V_\mathrm{CE}(Th.)$(T1) & $V_\mathrm{CE} (Th.)$(T2)
    & $V_\mathrm{BE}(P)$(T1)&
    $V_\mathrm{BE}(P)$(T2)
    &$V_\mathrm{R}$&
    $V_\mathrm{LED}$\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively (depending on the real contents of your table), you might swap rows and columns, if there are more columns than rows.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Geometry`, `noindent` and `scripts`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[margin={1cm,1cm}, paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\scriptsize
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    Modes & LED Status & $V_{CE}(P)$(T1)& $V_{CE}(P)$ (T2) & $V_{CE}(Th.)$(T1) & $V_{CE} (Th.)$(T2) & $V_{BE}(P)$(T1)& $V_{BE}(P)$(T2) &$V_{R}$& $V_{LED}$ \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

\end{document}

[image]